# Spotfire sumif in another table

Tags: spotfire

I have two tables. They are connected by date. And Date in table one is Unique.
I want to sum the values from table2 two in a column in table one.

Any tips?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irrMS.png)

```
Table 1         Table2  
Date    Sum     Date    Value
2023-08-01  4   2023-08-01  1
2023-08-02  10  2023-08-01  1
2023-08-03  3   2023-08-01  1
2023-08-04  17  2023-08-01  1
            2023-08-02  4
            2023-08-02  6
            2023-08-03  3
            2023-08-04  1
            2023-08-04  4
            2023-08-04  1
            2023-08-04  6
            2023-08-04  5
```

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the column on Table2 as:

```
Sum([Value]) over ([Date])
```

Then go to the Data Canvas and add the new column from Table2 to Table1 using

Add columns
match by Date
*Left single match join* for Join settings.